# Changing default option selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

Working on this lib- http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/

Trying to add a "Add New" item as an list item option always on top in list.

I find this plugin by someone - http://jsfiddle.net/qrqJv/26/

This person added "Clear Selection" but what I want is "Add New" and make is selectable too instead of clearing the textbox.

I tried my best @my understands but latest I end up is this,

http://jsfiddle.net/qrqJv/34/

It doesn't lets me change it, any help to right direction please ?

```
   Selectize.define( 'clear_selection', function ( options ) {
    var self = this;

    self.plugins.settings.dropdown_header = {
        title: 'Add New'
    };
    this.require( 'dropdown_header' );

    self.setup = (function () {
        var original = self.setup;

        return function () {
            original.apply( this, arguments );
            this.$dropdown.on( 'mousedown', '.selectize-dropdown-header', function ( e ) {
                self.setValue( 'Add New');
            });
        }
    })();
});

$('#test').selectize({
    create: false,
    dropdownParent: 'body',
    plugins: {
        'clear_selection': {}
    }
});
```

Comment: So you decide to use the first or second fiddle ?

Comment: Very hard to achieve that. Maybe this fiddle will help you : http://jsfiddle.net/zlen/gndrrvLp/

Comment: @Zl3n thanks for your efforts, what you added can be achieved by simply adding "create: true", anyway fiddle with bootstrap was breaking my other code, so I removed it from question now

Comment: So is your problem solved now, or I have to work on this new fiddle ?

Comment: @Zl3n my problem is still there, but I give up with it, I am trying jquery UI autocomplete instead. i will show you once done, thanks

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/xmpjLp56/) is what you want?

Comment: @CerlinBoss Yes, but Add New should stay even if search returns nothing, thanks